# jQuery Mobile Beta absolute/relative URL paths

Tags: url, jquery-mobile, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm trying to switch our mobile site from the jQuery Mobile Alpha to the latest Beta version. The problem is with the way the Beta handles URLs for dynamic pages.

Our live Alpha 4 site loads the dynamic pages as relative links (i.e. /#news/). The Beta 1 site loads the dynamic pages as absolute links (i.e. /#/group/webdev/cgi-bin/m/news/).

My question is, is there a way to change the jQuery Mobile Beta to handle URLs as the Alpha 4 version did?

Here are my pages (click the News link for an example):

[Live mobile site](http://bit.ly/oGlj1w) (jQuery Mobile Alpha 4)

[Dev mobile site](http://bit.ly/nmNPm8) (jQuery Mobile Beta 1)

Comment: How do the relative vs. absolute path solutions affect your website in a negative way? It seems as though the site still displays properly with Beta 1 and on a mobile device you won't see the long absolute path since you have to click on the address bar to view the actual address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are issues with relative paths. see 
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/wiki/Refactor:-navigation-paths

Comment: is this issue also replicating jquery mobile 1.4.5 mini?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me.

I modified the jquery mobile sourcecode and replaces the variable "newPath" with the following code:

```
var newPath = path.get( $('head base').attr('href') );
```

Works like a charm with relative paths and base href.